# 2007 Chevy Silverado 1500 LT how to repair door molding

Tags: chevrolet, door, silverado

The vehicle in question is a 2007 Chevy Silverado 1500 LT extended cab, 150k miles on the clock. A picture is worth 1000 words, so here's 2000 words about the problem:

[image: Side view of molding damage]

[image: End view showing separation]

It's a very wet day here in New England which is why everything is wet and has leaves stuck to it.

The question is how to fix this? Is there a kind of double stick tape that would actually last? Is it something I would glue on? I don't even know how to approach this in a way that lasts and isn't ugly.

Comment: there's automotive double stick tape for this kind of thing. I imagine 3m makes a good version.

Comment: That's what it's held on with now. I don't know what kind was used, but that's what failed. I was hoping there was a better solution.

Comment: It's used to hold on trim and emblems for all makes of vehicles across nearly all manufacturers. It will fail occasionally, but it's the best option. Glue, drywall screws, and duct tape are all viable options too, you pick which you think is best for your application.

Comment: Dry wall screws, because that will meet my criteria of lasting and not being ugly the best :) Especially if I don't drive them in all the way.  That's certainly the best way to go :)  I ordered the 3M tape yesterday lol I had hoped there might be a better alternative, which is why I asked here. If anyone would know of something better, it would be someone here. There isn't, so I'm going with the tape. Good to know I can fall back on duct tape. Because duct tape is always attractive and classy.

Answer (score 2):

A smear of a product like Tigerseal or Sikaflex behind the trim then hold it in place with a piece of masking tape for 24 hours (no longer as the tape can mark the paintwork).

Comment: Painter's tape may work better in not marring the finish, but good idea!

Comment: 3M makes a tape that is specifically for masking on automotive finishes, They guarantee it will not leave adhesive residue. I found it in my search for molding tape, which 3M also makes. Given the simplicity I'm going that route, but this is definitely a good idea, thank you @Steve Matthews